# How can I ignore operating system font in react-native?

Tags: typescript, react-native, fonts

I want to ignore the system operating font (iOS & Android) and use the various font that I used in my react-native project. I would like to do it only once, but I don't understand how. can you help me?

Answer (score 3):

**Add Fonts to Assets**

Add all the font files you want to an “assets/fonts” folder in the root of your react native project

**Package.json**

Next we need to tell React Native where our custom fonts are located. We do this by adding rnpm to package.json providing the path to the font files:

```
"rnpm": {
    "assets": [
    "./assets/fonts/"
    ]
},
```

Then we tell react native to link those font files for us:

```
react-native link
```

**On IOS**

This should add the font references in your Info.plist file for iOS and on Android copy the font files to android/app/src/main/assets/fonts. You can verify this by opening up Info.plist from the iOS folder and looking for a UIAppFonts key, you should see something similar to:

```
<key>UIAppFonts</key>
    <array>
        <string>YOUR_FONT_FILE.ttf</string>
    </array>
```

**On Android**

if you look in the file path “android/app/src/main/assets/fonts/” you should see your fonts have been copied over:

**React Native Styles**

With your fonts embedded and referenced it’s a simple case of adding them to your React Native styles. Simply add a fontFamily property with your font name:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#F5FCFF"
  },
  foo: {
    fontFamily: "YOUR_FONT_FAMILY_NAME",
    fontSize: 30,
    textAlign: "center",
    margin: 10
  },
  bar: {
    fontFamily: "YOUR_FONT_FAMILY_NAME",
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: "center",
    color: "#333333",
    marginBottom: 5
  }
});
```

Sources:

- https://medium.com/react-native-training/react-native-custom-fonts-ccc9aacf9e5e
- https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/using-custom-fonts/
- https://blog.bam.tech/developper-news/add-a-custom-font-to-your-react-native-app

Comment: I don't want a custom font. I already use a custom font. I want ignore the greatness text of system